# Per-library "Configuration File" value for run config for "All Tests" in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, monorepo, vitest

We have an NX monorepo, where each library has a `vite.config.mts` file that looks like this:

```js
import { makeConfig } from '../../../vite.config.base'

export default makeConfig({
  name: 'library-name',
  pathToRepoRoot: '../../../',
  projectDir: __dirname,
})
```

If I want to run a test through the Vitest Test Runner, it only works if I specify the full absolute path for the library's `vite.config.mts` in the "Configuration file" field of the run config. If I leave this out, the test runner complains of being unable to find code from other libraries, as well as Vitest globals like `describe`.

Running the nx targets to run the tests from the terminal (or through the WebStorm NX plugin as a run config) works fine but this is much less flexible than the test runner of course.

For individual files, this is a pain (I should just be able to click the gutter icon and have it just work) but still possible. However, if I want to run "All Tests" then obviously I can't supply all the config paths  for all the libraries. How would I make this work?

Similarly, if I wanted to more easily set up a config for any individual file, how would I do this? The test runner always runs Vitest and simply supplies the filename as an argument. Therefore there's not even any way to get something like `$currentFilelibraryRoot/vite.config.mts` since there's not even really a concept of "`currentFile`".

---

For what it's worth, Vitest runner *used* to "just work" in our project. Although for some reason I'm unable to use `git bisect` to diagnose this, I think it broke in a commit that switched from using `vite.config.js` to `vite.config.mts`, along with a few other things such as upgrading vite and vitest.

Did just the change in the config filename make this difference? Since specifying the `mts` file *does* work, as indicated above, I don't think the issue is the difference between the contents of the old `js` file (and the config it built from `vite.config.base`) and the new `mts` file.

I thought it was maybe as simple as WebStorm's Vite runner is (no longer) finding the "closest Vite config file" when that file is `.mts`, but changing the filename to `vite.config.js` doesn't fix it!